# Using IOC in a single namespace between classes

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have one namespace, which contains lots of classes (within various folder structures). A lot of these classes are dependent on each other, however.

Even in a single namespace, is this a place to use an IOC library (e.g. Autofaq)?

Thanks

Comment: Dependency Injection is a pattern to build _loosely coupled_ applications. If you have a lot of cross references between your classes (i.e. these classes are strongly coupled) I would recommend to disentangle those references first instead of throwing a tool at them.

Comment: Namespaces has nothing to do with dependency injection. You can use dependency injection even if all classes are in a single namespace. Namespace however, are there for a reason. They help you with grouping classes and thus keep your code base maintainable.

Comment: Thanks all. Sebestian, I guess you mean code to interfaces etc?

Comment: Developing against abstractions (interfaces/abstract base classes etc.) is part of the concept of DI. If you are looking for a really good introduction to the whole topic I would recommend to have a look at @MarkSeemann's book _Dependency Injection in .NET_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should have only one "composition root"  in the application (close to the entry point) where the components are wired together. That would be the only place where you use something like autofac.

Individual classes should not depend on a specific dependency injection framework. They should only conform to the general dependency injection principle, i.e. take dependencies through constructor arguments. Libraries shouldn't depend on a DI framework either.

(Not all DI frameworks make this possible. Some require you to add attributes to the classes. You can consider that an exception to the rule.)